# Pick up one column of varying lengths from many CSV files and merge to one matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, merge, dataframe

I have 1000 CSV files from [dfr.jstor.org](http://dfr.jstor.org/) with two columns, KEYWORDS and WEIGHT. The length of each column varies from file to file. Here's a snippet of one CSV file:

```
KEYTERMS  WEIGHT
canoe     1
archaic   0.273
pinus     0.191
florida   0.164
```

I want to use R to get the KEYTERMS column from each CSV file and merge it into a single data frame like this:

```
KEYTERMS_CSVFILENAME1 KEYTERMS_CSVFILENAME2 KEYTERMS_CSVFILENAME3
thwart                newsom                period 
dugout                site                  cypress 
sigma                 date                  hartmann 
precontact            NA                    florida 
orange                NA                    NA
```

Where CSVFILENAME1 is the name of the CSV file  where those keywords came from and NA is an empty cell.

I think my problem is very simliar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987310/pick-up-one-column-from-many-files-and-merge-to-one-matrix-in-r) with the difference that I have varying column lengths. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562124/merge-many-data-frames-from-csv-files) may also be relevant to a solution, and [this](http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/r-combining-vectors-or-data-frames-of-unequal-length-into-one-data-frame/) looks right on topic, but I need a bit of hand-holding to make it suit my situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is fairly open ended. How about you get started using the information from the questions you linked to and then come back when you have a specific problem?

Comment: Well I'm not exactly sure where to start! Any tips or clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try reading only two csv's into R and see if you can merge them.

Comment: Right, I can get two csv file in and merge them using cbind and the function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754474/cbind-two-data-frames-with-different-rownames-and-numbers-of-rows). Where to next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save a LITTLE memory/time you could modify the solution from @Ben Bolker like this:

```
datlist <- lapply(csvnames,read.csv, colClasses=c("character", "NULL"))
rowseq <- seq_len( max(vapply(datlist,nrow, integer(1))) )
keylist <- lapply(datlist,function(x) { x[[1]][rowseq] ) })
names(keylist) <- paste(KEYTERMS,csvnames,sep="_")
#do.call(cbind,keylist)
do.call(data.frame,keylist)
```

...I just changed so that only the first column is read, and simplified the NA padding by observing that selecting a sequence that extends outside a character vector pads with NA automatically...

If you kept the old way of padding, you should at least pad with `NA_character_` instead of `NA` to avoid unnecessary coercion.

I also index the `KEYTERMS` column by number instead of name (since there should be only one). I also changed `sapply` to `vapply` because I like it better :) - it actually is faster too.

Finally you said you wanted a `data.frame`. The last line produces that instead of a matrix.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks very much! I just took a `)` out of line two after `[rowseq]`and changed `KEYTERMS` to `"KEYTERMS"` and it's done the job perfectly. Very instructive, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't constrained by memory space at all, something like:

```
datlist <- lapply(csvnames,read.csv)
maxlen <- max(sapply(datlist,nrow))
pad.NA <- function(x,len) {
   c(x,rep(NA_character_,len-length(x)))
}
keylist <- lapply(datlist,function(x) { pad.na(x[["KEYTERMS"]],maxlen) })
names(keylist) <- paste(KEYTERMS,csvnames,sep="_")
do.call(cbind,keylist)
```

might work (**edit**: added missing parenthesis, `NA_character_`)

Comment: Thanks, I can see what you've done with lapply and sapply there, that's helpful. But I get this message `Error: unexpected '}' in: "c(x,rep(NA,len-length(x))
}"` at the end of the block...

Comment: .@Ben - add an end parenthesis then : `c(x,rep(NA,len-length(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly simpler solution using `ldply` from `plyr` and `reshape` from `base`

```
# READ CSV FILES INTO LIST (i am using a dummy datlist for illustration)
# datlist <- lapply(csvnames,read.csv, colClasses=c("character", "NULL"))
datlist <- list(
  file1 = data.frame(KEYWORDS = c('thwart', 'dugout', 'sigma', 'precontact')),
  file2 = data.frame(KEYWORDS = c('newsom', 'site', 'date'))
)

# BIND THEM INTO A DATAFRAME AND RESHAPE TO DESIRED FORM
datdf <- plyr::ldply(datlist, function(x) data.frame(x, id = 1:NROW(x)))
reshape(datdf, timevar = '.id', direction = 'wide', sep = "_") 

   id KEYWORDS_file1 KEYWORDS_file2
1  1         thwart         newsom
2  2         dugout           site
3  3          sigma           date
4  4     precontact           <NA>
```